# How to build camera app to match vary size of device?

Tags: java, android, camera, fullscreen

I have built camera android application. Also have to draw a rectangle and circle on surface view. My test device is Tablet Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1. I have try to run application on my friend's mobile, that is Samsung Galaxy S3. So, it was so different. The rectangle and circle is not located in right position. how I will fix that the rectangle and circle will locate in the same position on Galaxy Note 10.1?.
Here is my code building camera app.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CaptureCamera extends Activity { 

//** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

Camera mCamera = null; 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_start); 
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    Preview mPreview = new Preview(this, mCamera); 
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cam_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenCenterX = (size.x /4);
    int screenCenterY = (size.y/6) ;
    DrawOnTop mDraw = new DrawOnTop(this,screenCenterX,screenCenterY); 
    addContentView(mDraw, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

    //Adding listener
    ImageView captureButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

            }
        });

  //Adding listener
    ImageView backButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(CaptureCamera.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);



            }
        });

    //Adding listener
    ImageView nextButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_next);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(CaptureCamera.this, ProcessPic.class);
                startActivity(intent2);

            }
        });
} 
/**
 * Helper method to access the camera returns null if
 * it cannot get the camera or does not exist
 * @return
 */
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera camera = null;

    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // cannot get camera or does not exist
    }
    return camera;
}
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
         File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null){
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                Toast.makeText(CaptureCamera.this, "Photo saved to folder \"sdcard\\DCIM\\CameraSnap\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
    }
};

private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "CameraSnap");
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("CameraSnap", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    //String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    //    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
    //    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +"IMG_0"+".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}
} 

//--------------------------------------------------------------------//
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {  

SurfaceHolder mHolder; 
Camera mCamera; 
Preview(Context context, Camera camera) { 
    super(context); 
    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when 
    this.mCamera = camera;
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed. 
    mHolder = getHolder(); 
    mHolder.addCallback(this); 
  //this is a deprecated method, is not required after 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
} 

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell 
    // to draw. 

    try {

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
} 


public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the 
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, 
    // important to release it when the activity is paused. 
    mCamera.stopPreview(); 
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null; 

} 

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) { 
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters 
    // the preview. 
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
    Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);



    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.startPreview();

}
```

}

and this is a code for drawing rectangle and circle.

```
class DrawOnTop extends View { 
int screenCenterX = 0;
int screenCenterY = 0;
final int radius = 80;
    public DrawOnTop(Context context, int screenCenterX, int screenCenterY) { 
            super(context); 
           this.screenCenterX = screenCenterX;
           this.screenCenterY = screenCenterY;
     } 


    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
         Paint paint = new Paint(); 
         Paint p = new Paint();
         p.setColor(Color.RED);
         paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         DashPathEffect dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{5,5}, (float)1.0);
         p.setPathEffect(dashPath);
         p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
         //paint.setPathEffect();
         paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
         p.setStrokeWidth(3);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        // paint.setPathEffect();
         //paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

         canvas.drawCircle(3*screenCenterX, 2*screenCenterY, radius, p);
         canvas.drawCircle(3*screenCenterX, 4*screenCenterY, radius, p);
         canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 360, 700, paint);
         invalidate();
         super.onDraw(canvas); 
    } 
}
```

Before this, I faced the problem that when I use this camera app. I looked stretched. So,I fix it by set size of frame layout like this.

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/cam_preview"
    android:layout_width="1120dp"
    android:layout_height="840dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.91" >

</FrameLayout>
```

But i just know that it not a good idea when use in other device. 
So now i don't know how to fix it for my camera app is not stretch and the drawing in rectangle and circle is on the same position in vary device.
note that : spec of Camera of Galaxy Note 10.1 is 1200x800 pixel

Answer (score 0):

Galaxy Note 10.1 and Samsung Galaxy S3 are two different size. To supporting multiple screens read this documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html